# What is the meaning of Weiss's answer to Mary's question?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Weiss asking Mary about her daughter Precious who got sexually abused.

> Weiss: Okay, Mrs. Johnston, let's talk about the abuse.
>
> Mary: There were no drugs in my house. I didn't play that. There
>   weren't no drugs in my house. Precious knew I would whup her ass if
>   she gonna bring some drugs up in my house.
>
> Weiss: You know what I'm talking about. I'm referring to specific
>   sexual and physical acts involving Precious.
>
> Mary: **Why you ain't say that?**
>
> Weiss: **Yes, that.**

Weiss replied somewhat different to Wiess's Question. What is the meaning of "**Yes, that**" in this context?

The source is the opening of the film *Precious* (2009), [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L26bnfsPb2A).

Comment: Source of this context please!

Comment: added the source to the post.

Comment: "Weiss replied somewhat different to Wiess's Question." I do not understand what you asking here.

Comment: OP edited it but for some reason @StoneyB changed it back. Weiss has not asked any question.

Comment: @WeatherVane I added a link to the film itself, because this isn't really about the text but the subtext.

Comment: I would rather like to know, what "**Why you ain't say that?**" means.

Comment: The meaning of "Why you ain't say that?" is "Why didn't you say that?"

Comment: Weiss has not asked a literal interrogative in the given exchange, but the context is that Weiss is questioning events in the house. Weiss' question (implied) is "what abuse transpired?"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't really about the language but about the motives and actions which evoke the language--it involves dramatic criticism, not linguistics.

Comment: As a side note, that's a pretty dark scene, that I wish I hadn't watched after just waking up.

Comment: I think the question is language-related. @StoneyB's answer hits the nail on the head when he states that Mary takes **abuse** to mean **drug abuse**. In that regard, her reply "Why ain't you say that?" (i.e. why didn't...) is not a non-sequitur, as OP believed it to be.  Whether Mary is feigning not to understand the gist of Weiss's question does goes beyond language. But we can describe the scene in terms of its conversational flow.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I'd agree, except that OP's question is about Weiss' "Yes, that", which is a clear override of Mary's attempt to divert the 'conversational flow'.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the speech patterns involved here are so far from "standard English" that they're more likely to be a source of confusion than enlightenment to people who aren't native speakers (and thus probably don't even know immediately *which* aspects of the text are non-standard).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*NOTE: I’ve voted to close this question, because as I explain below it’s about the drama, not the language; but I thought it might be of value to ELL to have the difference set out explicitly.*

Except in formal discourses such as academic and literary essays, language does not follow linear discursive logic: speech acts are driven by what actors call “subtext”, the underlying intentions of the speakers.

This scene starts with the social worker Weiss trying to move the conversation into a very threatening area: the abuse Precious suffered. Precious’ mother Mary reacts defensively by affecting to understand “abuse” as possible drug abuse by Precious. Weiss dismisses this ploy and makes her concern more explicit. Still trying to avoid the issue, Mary tries to blame the misunderstanding on Weiss—“Why you ain't say that?” = “Why didn't you say that?”—but Weiss ignores this ploy, too, and reiterates that it is sexual abuse—"Yes, that"—she is concerned with.

Don’t follow the words alone; follow the ***actions***, of which the words are merely a trace.

Comment: I disagree that this is about drama. it's about the referent or antecedent of the word that and I can understand perfectly why it might be confusing to someone.

Comment: I closevoted for a different reason. But you're quite right that *Yeah, that* is just shorthand for something like *Yeah, **that's** what I'm talking about* (but is this feature of spoken language particularly relevant to *English?*).